# App is failing with "required a bean of type 'brave.Tracer' that could not be found" while trying to get Sleuth's trace

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am calling my Springboot app from another micro service to get the trace & span id's but getting error while starting the app.
What I want to do is create Trace & Span in app1 and then call app2 and get the Trace id passed from app1 in app2. In app1 I am able to get the trace & span but in app2 where I want to fetch that trace its failing. I have tried to refer [this](https://github.com/robert07ravikumar/sleuth-sample/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo).

Error that I get is:

> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.demo1.filter.MyFilter required a bean of type 'brave.Tracer' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'brave.Tracer' in your configuration."
> I also tried creating the bean but is giving error "The constructor Tracer() is undefined"

Below is my simple RestController & pom.xml

```
package com.test.demo1.controller;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import brave.Tracer;


@RestController
@Component
public class Greeting {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Greeting.class.getName());
    
    @Autowired
    Tracer tracer;

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        logger.info("Hello info from from spring sleuth");
        logger.info("tracer is -----> "+tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString());
        System.out.println("tracer-id :"+ tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString());
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.opentracing.brave/brave-opentracing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-opentracing</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
                
                  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring.boot}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
       
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.zipkin.brave/brave -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
                
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What to do to fix this or achieve this?

Below is my mvn clean dependency:tree  :--

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-log4j2:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-web:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpclient:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpasyncclient:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-webmvc:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-servlet:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-jms:jar:5.6.1:compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided Sleuth in version 1.0.0 which is a couple of years old. Please go to start.spring.io to generate a project with Sleuth as its dependency. Then you'll be sure that you don't have mixed up the dependencies manually.

Example of proper setup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Tried updating the sleuth version but same result.     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>

Comment: to add below is "mvn clean dependency:tree"

Comment: Please don't say any versions yourself. You're using boot 2.3 so you should be using sleuth 2.2. Please use the spring cloud bom as suggested in the documentation and by start.spring.io

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of a proper setup

Comment: this got fixed if I changed the pom from <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>  to   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId> . But do you know how did this relates to Bean not found error that Spring boot was throwing, could you please help me to understand.

Comment: Most likely You had two versions of sleuth on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot V3.0 & above  `brave.Trace` is not supported.

Use `org.apache.htrace` instead of brave package

```java
import org.apache.htrace.impl.MilliSpan;
import org.apache.htrace.Trace;

String traceId = Long.toString(new MilliSpan.Builder().build().getTraceId());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).